# What is the difference between RCDATA and User-Defined Resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource

Is there a difference between RCDATA and User-Defined Resource? Is RCDATA just a common name for a User-Defined Resource?

Comment: As far as I know there is no difference.

Comment: "Defines a raw data resource for an application. Raw data resources permit the inclusion of binary data directly in the executable file"

Comment: The difference is in the resource type. A user-defined resource's type is the name you gave it. The type of RCDATA is RT_RCDATA.

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of resources that are suitable for storing user defined data.

1. The first kind has a type of RCDATA (raw data). Windows knows the type of the resource but doesn't know how to interpret the resource data itself.
2. The second kind is any resource whose type is not defined by Windows. In this case, Windows knows neither the type of the resource nor how to interpret the resource data.

You can use either kind of resource for user defined data.

I believe that it is the second kind of resource that Windows considers to be a user defined resource. Here is a list of the [System defined resource types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The Type member of the [RESOURCEHEADER sructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains what a user defined resource is.

Comment: So is it wrong to think of RCDATA as being a user defined resource created by Windows for us to use? Is it better to just think of it as a binary resource type, and that user defined resource also happens to store binary data, without any relation between the two?

Comment: I tried to avoid using the term "user defined resource" in my answer because it seems to mean different things to different people. To some people it seems to mean a resource of type RCDATA (which by the way is a resource type defined by Windows), but the MSDN documentation I have read, seem to use the term to mean a resource whose type is user defined. As for the best way to think about these things, I can't really say which way is best for you.

Comment: This is starting to seem like a philosophical question lol, anyway I think it's better to think of them as meaning the same thing (they both store binary data) but with just different type names.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a difference between RCDATA and User-Defined Resource?"*

If I read up [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381039(v=vs.85).aspx) it says

> RCDATA resource
>   *Defines a raw data resource for an application. Raw data resources permit the inclusion of binary data directly in the executable file.*

Also it says

> CHARACTERISTICS | dword   | **User-defined information** about a resource that can be used by tools that read and write resource files. For more information, see CHARACTERISTICS.

---

> *"Is RCDATA just a common name for a User-Defined Resource?"*

So I'd say, it can be considered there's no real difference, but just `RCDATA` is the keyword to use for a *User-Defined Resource* in your resource (`.rc`) file.