# Extracting an an image (JPG or PNG) from the PE

Tags: c++, image, resources, extract, portable-executable

First of all I have done a lot of research on how to use resources and I cannot find proper documentation or manage to make it work so please do not link documentation without explaining (I am using Visual Studio 2015).
The problem is the following I would like to extract an image (JPG or PNG) that is in the PE.
I found 2 approaches:

1. Using resources but I can't seem to find documentation for PNG files and on how to properly declare the resource ID.
2. Converting the image to a hex array and copy it to a file, this solution isn't working because Visual Studio simply doesn't allow me to paste the array (maybe too big?) And just crashes. Modifying the file directly in the project with another editor doesn't seem to work either it just reverts back for whatever reason.

I don't mind the solution to use but none is working right now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236561/what-is-the-difference-between-rcdata-and-user-defined-resource

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a few more hours of researches I found this and it seems to work.
Posting it in case someone has the same problem :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d753874-2fed-4db7-8135-4e4d499bac99/how-use-rcdata?forum=Vsexpressvc